# Getting titles of a list as a link

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am using javascript to get titles of a list. Now when I have to display these titles, I have to display it as a link.

I am using the below code

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("retrieveListItems");
var siteUrl = '../HRM/';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var ID= oListItem.get_id();
        listItemInfo += '\n' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerText =listItemInfo;

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
<div id="myDiv1" />
</html>
```

where should I edit this code so that the titles come as a link?

Comment: SharePoint does not use titles to link to an item, you have to get the list item ID as well to create a hyperlink to the lists displayform liks this: Url/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=[ID]

Comment: yes, I am also asking the same thing. After getting ID,where in code i have to make changes so that titles come as link(based on ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this line in the loop to get the hyperlink working.

```
   var href = oList.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + ID;
```